# PHP; MySQL; calcular/ inserir dados automaticamente de acordo com certos parâmetros

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, funções

Boa tarde, tenho 3 tabelas.
[image: base de dados]

Quero calcular e inserir automaticamente os horários na tabela escalas de acordo  com alguns parâmetros.
ex:
4 dias trabalho manhãs, 2 dias de folga, 4 dias de trabalho tarde (dados tabela horários id-1 = manhã; id-2 = tarde; id-3 = folga)

por exemplo para um ano ou mais

Muito obrigado, Rui

Comment: Eu não percebi, muito bem a ideia, mas pelo que quer fazer, tem que fazer um select, na primeira tabela, de seguida fazer um mysql_fetch_array ou assoc, e de seguida inserir na outra em que deseja.

Comment: Também pode fazer logo, diretamente com while.

Comment: O que você já tentou? Recebeu algum erro?

Comment: Eu sou muito noob nisto. De qualquer maneira o meu problema são os parâmetros (4 dias manhã, 2 folga, 4 dias tarde) ou seja 4 dias id=1, 2 dias id=3 e 4 dias id=2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, parece que consegui dar a volta ao meu problema!
Fica a solução (pelo menos temporária)

```
//criar o array (primeiros dois dias folga 1 e 2)
$arrayTurno = array('1','2');
//verifico qual o fim do array
$end = array_slice($arrayTurno, -1, 1);
//verifico qual o ultimo turno antes das folgas (manhã 1, manhã 2, tarde 1 ou tarde 2)
$lastTurno  = array_slice($arrayTurno, -3, 1);
//Verifico qual o ultimo turmo de manhã (3 manhã 1 e 5 manhã 2) 
$lastM  = array_slice($arrayTurno, -6, 1);


    // se o turno apenas tem apenas 2 dias (folgas) acrescenta 4 dias de manhã 1
    if (count($arrayTurno) < 3 and $end = '2') {
    array_push($arrayTurno, '3','3','3','3');
    }
    // se já existe 1 turno ou + verifica se é manhã 1 (se assim for acrescenta folgas + tarde 1)
    if (count($arrayTurno) > 3 and $lastTurno = '3') {
    array_push($arrayTurno, '1','2','4','4','4','4');
    }
    // se já existe 1 turno ou + verifica se é tarde 1 (se assim for acrescenta folgas + manhã 2)
    if (count($arrayTurno) > 3 and $lastM = '4') {
    array_push($arrayTurno, '1','2','5','5','5','5');
    }
    // se já existe 1 turno ou + verifica se é manhã 2 (se assim for acrescenta folgas + tarde 2)   
    if (count($arrayTurno) > 3 and $lastM = '5') {
    array_push($arrayTurno, '1','2','6','6','6','6');
    }

// acabo de encher o array até ficar com o comprimento do total de datas
$max = mysqli_num_rows($resultData);

        $newArrayTurno = array();

        while(count($newArrayTurno) <= $max){
            $newArrayTurno = array_merge($newArrayTurno, $arrayTurno);
        }

        $arrayTurno = array_slice($newArrayTurno, 0, $max);
```

no final é só inserir na tabela.

Obrigado, cumprimentos, Rui

Comment: pode colocar a parte do código para inserir na tabela?